# How to get all values of any particular field from any object by search method in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, search, odoo, environment-variables, odoo-10

I created a master table for estimated weight. For this master table i have two float fields 'min' and 'max'. Now i have 10 records and in every record there is 'min' and 'max' value. Now i want to show all 'min' and 'max' values from table to another place. For this i use search method, but not reached upto the mark. So, How can i do that?

**Python Code:**

*Master Table code --*

```
class est_weight(models.Model):
    _name = "est.weight"
    _rec_name = 'est_weight_pet'

    min = fields.Float("Min. Weight")
    max = fields.Float("Max. Weight")
    est_weight_price = fields.Integer(string="Price")
```

*Here i want to search all min. and max. value:--*

```
class RentalPackWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "rental.pack.wizard"
    _description = "Rental Pack Wizard"

    @api.model
    def _get_min_max(self):
        mini = self.env['est.weight'].search([('min', '=', '')], limit=1)
        maxi = self.env['est.weight'].search([('max', '=', '')], limit=1)
```

Also image attached below[image].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create field for Est.Weight(kg). like:

```
est_weight = fields.Char(string="Est.Weight", compute=_cal_min_max_weight)
@api.depends('min', 'max')
def _cal_min_max_weight(self):
    #list of ids from database
    for m in self:
        if m.min and m.max:
            m.est_weight = str(m.min) + '-' + str(m.max)
```

Instead of self model you have to browse another model and calculate field value.
in place of self :

```
obj = self.env['est.weight']
```

Find list of ids. and apply for loop and find values for est_weight